# Is JSP rendering a client-side or server side in SPRING MVC web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, single-page-application

I am using Spring MVC to develop my web applications using JSP and JavaScript/jQuery for front end . With these front-end tech, is view rendering a client-side or server-side rendering as I am in a assumption that all web applications developed with using Struts or Spring MVC are client side rendering as We can see that the view is the presentation layer of an application which is rendered in a user’s browser.

**which one is correct in the below?**

1. JSP is a server side technology but it is rendered in user browser which is a client side. Can i say it is a client side rendering?
2. As Spring controller process the request and returns the result to view using model which is happening at server side , Can I say it is Server side rendering?

This is how MVC works.The client connects to the server and makes a request. That request is handled by a controller (the C). The controller processes the request using the model (the M) and returns the result using the view (the V).

Comment: The name already says it: Java **Server** Pages (JSP). With "rendering", in a webapp what is usually meant is "generating HTML". With JSP this happens on the server, so it's server-side rendering.

Answer (score 6):

> JSP allows Java code and certain predefined actions to be interleaved
>   with static web markup content, such as HTML, with the resulting page
>   **being compiled and executed on the server to deliver a document.**

If it's compiled and executed on the server, it is server side rendering. After it's done with server rendering, it delivers HTML content, that is rendered in a browser.

Comment: As JSP compilations and conversion to servlet and execution on server side , Can i say it is server side rendering?
As html content rendered in a browser, Can i say it is client side rendering?

Comment: HTML rendering isn't considered client side rendering. Client side rendering is using Javascript to access change the state of the HTML DOM on the client side.